# Change Character to time stamp in IBM informix DB

Tags: sql, informix

I am writing a query to convert a character to Date Time

The following query extracts my time stamps in Character format.

```
select
(to_char(TO_CHAR(MDY(month(current- 1 units month), 1,year(current- 1 units month)),'%Y-%m-%d')||' 13:00:00')),
(to_char(TO_CHAR((DATE(DATE(extend(TODAY, YEAR TO MONTH)) - 1 UNITS DAY)+1),'%d-%m-%Y')||' 13:00:00'))
from dual
```

Output:

```
`T 0÷ 
2015-08-01 13:00:00     01-09-2015 13:00:00
2015-08-01 13:00:00     01-09-2015 13:00:00
```

Now I am trying to convert the Character to Time stamp using DATETIME(2001-12-31 15:32:55) YEAR TO SECOND function. I am getting syntax error.

```
select
DATETIME(to_char(TO_CHAR(MDY(month(current- 1 units month), 1,year(current- 1 units month)),'%Y-%m-%d')||' 13:00:00')) YEAR TO SECOND ,
DATETIME(to_char(TO_CHAR((DATE(DATE(extend(TODAY, YEAR TO MONTH)) - 1 UNITS DAY)+1),'%d-%m-%Y')||' 13:00:00') ) YEAR TO SECOND
from dual
```

How ever the following is working fine:

```
select DATETIME(2001-12-31 15:32:55) YEAR TO SECOND
from dual
```

Thanks in Advance. Please do not suggest answers for Oracle. its damn easy in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CAST to convert your output as a `DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND`:

```
select
(to_char(TO_CHAR(MDY(month(current- 1 units month), 1,year(current- 1 units month)),'%Y-%m-%d')||' 13:00:00'))::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND ,
(to_char(TO_CHAR((DATE(DATE(extend(TODAY, YEAR TO MONTH)) - 1 UNITS DAY)+1),'%Y-%m-%d')||' 13:00:00'))::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND
from dual
```

That seems to work OK, **but I'd suggest you don't do this**. Also, note that `DATETIME` is an ISO standard: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.FFF` (or part thereof). Your second example with the date in English format is not going to parse to a `DATETIME`.

Your first algorithm is not leap-day safe, and the second example is horribly over-complicated. You can determine 13:00 on the first day of the current month using the far simpler construction:

`(TODAY-DAY(TODAY)+1)::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND + INTERVAL(13) HOUR TO HOUR`

This also has the benefit of avoiding casting back and forth between `DATE` and `CHAR`. The calculation of the same time the previous month can be written as:

`MDY(MONTH(TODAY-DAY(TODAY)),1,YEAR(TODAY-DAY(TODAY)))::DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND + INTERVAL(13) HOUR TO HOUR`

... which will do the right thing on Feb 29/March 1 in a leap year, which your algorithm won't.

The construction `TODAY-DAY(TODAY)` will always produce the last day of the prior month.